# Weird underscores between images. What are they?

Tags: html, css, image

Im working on an image gallery for my site. When you click on the square thumbnail a larger image gallery opens up fullscree. I'd like to style the thumbnails, but for some reason they all have weird small black underscores between them.

What should I look for in the CSS that could be causing these? (got the gallery off of Github so I'll be looking through someone else's CSS)

[image]

I circled the underscores in photoshop. I thought it might be some sort of border, but I don't think so as I couldn't find one in the css

The HTML and CSS:

```css
.blueimp-gallery,
.blueimp-gallery>.slides>.slide>.slide-content {
  position: static;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden
}
.blueimp-gallery>.slides>.slide>.slide-content {
  margin: auto;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  opacity: 1
}
.blueimp-gallery {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999999;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #000;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
  direction: ltr;
  -ms-touch-action: none;
  touch-action: none
}
.blueimp-gallery-carousel {
  position: relative;
  z-index: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
  touch-action: pan-y
}
.blueimp-gallery-display {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1
}
.blueimp-gallery>.slides {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden
}
.blueimp-gallery-carousel>.slides {
  position: absolute
}
.blueimp-gallery>.slides>.slide {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.645, .045, .355, 1);
  -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.645, .045, .355, 1);
  -ms-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.645, .045, .355, 1);
  -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.645, .045, .355, 1);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.645, .045, .355, 1)
}
.blueimp-gallery,
.blueimp-gallery>.slides>.slide>.slide-content {
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s linear;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s linear;
  -ms-transition: opacity .5s linear;
  -o-transition: opacity .5s linear;
  transition: opacity .5s linear
}
.blueimp-gallery>.slides>.slide-loading {
  background: url(../img/loading.gif) center no-repeat;
  background-size: 64px 64px
}
.blueimp-gallery>.slides>.slide-loading>.slide-content {
  opacity: 0
}
.blueimp-gallery>.slides>.slide-error {
  background: url(../img/error.png) center no-repeat
}
.blueimp-gallery>.slides>.slide-error>.slide-content {
  display: none
}
.blueimp-gallery>.prev,
.blueimp-gallery>.next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 15px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: -23px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px #000;
  text-align: center;
  background: #222;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 23px;
  -moz-border-radius: 23px;
  border-radius: 23px;
  opacity: .5;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none
}
.blueimp-gallery>.next {
  left: auto;
  right: 15px
}
.blueimp-gallery>.close,
.blueimp-gallery>.title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  margin: 0 40px 0 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px #000;
  opacity: .8;
  display: none
}
.blueimp-gallery>.close {
  padding: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  left: auto;
  margin: -15px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer
}
.blueimp-gallery>.play-pause {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: url(../img/play-pause.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .5;
  display: none
}
.blueimp-gallery-playing>.play-pause {
  background-position: -15px 0
}
.blueimp-gallery>.prev:hover,
.blueimp-gallery>.next:hover,
.blueimp-gallery>.close:hover,
.blueimp-gallery>.title:hover,
.blueimp-gallery>.play-pause:hover {
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 1
}
.blueimp-gallery-controls>.prev,
.blueimp-gallery-controls>.next,
.blueimp-gallery-controls>.close,
.blueimp-gallery-controls>.title,
.blueimp-gallery-controls>.play-pause {
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0)
}
.blueimp-gallery-single>.prev,
.blueimp-gallery-left>.prev,
.blueimp-gallery-single>.next,
.blueimp-gallery-right>.next,
.blueimp-gallery-single>.play-pause {
  display: none
}
.blueimp-gallery>.slides>.slide>.slide-content,
.blueimp-gallery>.prev,
.blueimp-gallery>.next,
.blueimp-gallery>.close,
.blueimp-gallery>.play-pause {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none
}
body:last-child .blueimp-gallery>.slides>.slide-error {
  background-image: url(../img/error.svg)
}
body:last-child .blueimp-gallery>.play-pause {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-size: 40px 20px;
  background-image: url(../img/play-pause.svg)
}
body:last-child .blueimp-gallery-playing>.play-pause {
  background-position: -20px 0
}
*+html .blueimp-gallery>.slides>.slide {
  min-height: 300px
}
*+html .blueimp-gallery>.slides>.slide>.slide-content {
  position: relative
}
.blueimp-gallery>.indicator {
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  margin: 0 40px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 10px;
  display: none
}
.blueimp-gallery>.indicator>li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 9px;
  height: 9px;
  margin: 6px 3px 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background: #ccc;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .25)center no-repeat;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #000;
  opacity: .5;
  cursor: pointer
}
.blueimp-gallery>.indicator>li:hover,
.blueimp-gallery>.indicator>.active {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #fff;
  opacity: 1
}
.blueimp-gallery-controls>.indicator {
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0)
}
.blueimp-gallery-single>.indicator {
  display: none
}
.blueimp-gallery>.indicator {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none
}
*+html .blueimp-gallery>.indicator>li {
  display: inline
}
.h3 {
  font-family: Georgia, Times, Time New Roman, serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="links">
  <a href="img/landscapes/brs.jpg" title="">
    <img src="img/thumbnails/brs.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="img/landscapes/ela.jpg" title="">
    <img src="img/thumbnails/ela.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="img/landscapes/farm.jpg" title="">
    <img src="img/thumbnails/farm.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="img/landscapes/first.jpg" title="">
    <img src="img/thumbnails/first.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="img/landscapes/hf.jpg" title="">
    <img src="img/thumbnails/hf.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="img/landscapes/lindy.jpg" title="">
    <img src="img/thumbnails/lindy.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="img/landscapes/lp.jpg" title="">
    <img src="img/thumbnails/lp.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="img/landscapes/mcafee.jpg" title="">
    <img src="img/thumbnails/mcafee.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="img/landscapes/meth.jpg" title="">
    <img src="img/thumbnails/meth.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="img/landscapes/nr.jpg" title="">
    <img src="img/thumbnails/nr.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href="img/landscapes/d.jpg" title="">
    <img src="img/thumbnails/d.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: `text-decoration` css property?

Comment: Post your code in your question please. And it looks like hyperlink styling. But without a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question, who knows?

Comment: Code added. Was hesitant to put it in since it's a lot of lines

Answer (score 2):

Remove underline (`text-decoration: none`) from you anchor elements.

```css
#links > a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="links">
    <a href="img/landscapes/brs.jpg" title="">
        <img src="img/thumbnails/brs.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="img/landscapes/ela.jpg" title="">
        <img src="img/thumbnails/ela.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="img/landscapes/farm.jpg" title="">
        <img src="img/thumbnails/farm.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
     <a href="img/landscapes/first.jpg" title="">
        <img src="img/thumbnails/first.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="img/landscapes/hf.jpg" title="">
        <img src="img/thumbnails/hf.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="img/landscapes/lindy.jpg" title="">
        <img src="img/thumbnails/lindy.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
     <a href="img/landscapes/lp.jpg" title="">
        <img src="img/thumbnails/lp.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="img/landscapes/mcafee.jpg" title="">
        <img src="img/thumbnails/mcafee.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="img/landscapes/meth.jpg" title="">
        <img src="img/thumbnails/meth.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
     <a href="img/landscapes/nr.jpg" title="">
        <img src="img/thumbnails/nr.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="img/landscapes/d.jpg" title="">
        <img src="img/thumbnails/d.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
</div>
```